# WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget when importing ~@angular/material/theming

Tags: angular, angular-material

I import ~@angular/material/theming into many of my .scss files so that I have access to material colour palets.

After updating to Angular 9, I've been getting the following build warning:

> WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for [.scss file path]. Budget 6 kB
>   was not met by 202 kB with a total of 208 kB.

Most of this budget overflow is from importing ~@angular/material/theming. Is it ok to increase budgets in `angular.json` to ~2-500kB, what are the drawbacks of doing this?

Comment: you can change in angular.json in projects-->architect-->build-->budgets-->maximunError by, e.g. `5mb` (or whatever you need)

Comment: I needed to edit the maximumWarning in angular.json. projects > architect > build > configurations > (production,dev qa ...)> budgets > maximumWarning

Answer (score 20):

Besides `~@angular/material/theming`, was `mat-core()` also  imported accidentally? According to [Angular Material document](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming):

> **This should only be included once in your application.** If this mixin is included multiple times, your application will end up with multiple copies of these common styles.

For my case, I just wanted to access the `$primary` and `$accent` colors in my own css files. Here's what I did:

Create a `_variables.scss`, that can be imported anywhere throughout the app

```css
@import "~@angular/material/theming";
$primaryPalette: mat-palette($mat-pink, 700);
$accentPalette:  mat-palette($mat-blue-grey, A200, A100, A400);
$warnPalette:    mat-palette($mat-red);

$theme: mat-dark-theme($primaryPalette, $accentPalette, $warnPalette);

$primary: map-get($theme, primary);
$accent: map-get($theme,accent);
$background: map-get($theme, background);
$foreground: map-get($theme, foreground);
```

Create a `theme.scss`, and add it into `angular.json`'s `styles` array

```css
@import "~@angular/material/theming";
@import "_variables";
@include mat-core();
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

And then everything works, without inflating the compiled css.

Comment: Thanks! works for me.
In other words, all you need to do is to seperate the "@include" lines from the variables definitions, and move them to (one of) the global scss file.

Answer (score 2):

Same error happened to me when using `ng xi18n`

Try to move your angular.json `budgets` from:

```
architect.build.options.budgets
```

to:

```
architect.build.configurations.production.budgets
```

Check angular docs https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-size-budgets :

> Define your size boundaries in the CLI configuration file, angular.json, in a budgets section for each configured environment.